# Getting `querySelector` error when using Protractor's `browser.driver.switchTo().frame()` method

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, selenium, protractor

Have a protractor test that uses IE11 using compatibility mode to emulate IE8. The test is using the `browser.driver.switchTo().frame("frameName")` method to switch to the frame to input some values in controls. However, when it tries to make this call I get the below error.

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector'.
```

I've tried using different versions of the IEDriver for selenium - 2.39, 2.42, and the current latest of 2.57.

I've run this with Protractor versions 2.5.1 and the current version of 3.1.1 and they all get the same issue.

The URL itself isn't set to compatibility view, but it still fails whether it is or not.

Is there some IE setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try locating the frame element first and then switching to it:

```
var frame = driver.findElement(By.name("frameName"));
browser.driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```